# SQL query 'Where in (List)' in odata service call

Tags: odata, sapui5

I want to fetch multiple records from Hana DB using oData service after filtering the data. 
Issue is oData allows reading of only one record at a time.
How can I achieve this.
Is there a query where I can fetch the data based upon a list of input filters (say material number).

Example :

> SELECT column-names   FROM table-name  WHERE column-name IN (values)
>   (where is not available in oData service)

Comment: Can you post what you have so far? You can provide a list of filters to the oData service (also multiple filters with the same property). That's how you can fill your WHERE list in the GET_ENTITY_SET.

Comment: Hi @luuksen , in our application the data is in millions hence we need to fetch only the user specified records.
Say Out of 100 material numbers user want the value of 50 materials.
Also we have calculation view at the backend for one record the service is consuming 20 seconds ,do we have any List criteria in oData so that i can fetch all the selected materials data in one go